# Long-running access to a shared resource with the ability to release on request

Tags: c#, .net, locking

I'm not sure how to best explain what I want, so let me write some illustrative code. Basically: a background thread loops through lots of work, but on rare occasions it needs to be interrupted.

```
// This loop runs in a long-running thread that does
// a lot of high-priority work on a shared resource.
// The vast majority of time it is the only thread accessing the resource.
private void FastLoop()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DoWork();

            // Somehow checking if another thread needs the shared resource.
            // Ideally I'd like something like this,
            // but alas: Monitor.BlockedCount() doesn't exist.
            while (Monitor.BlockedCount(locker) > 0)
                Monitor.Wait(locker);
        }
    }
}

// Methods like this get called rarely, but there is many of them
// so the code required to lock and unlock from secondary threads
// should be simple.
private void OtherThreads()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
        Monitor.Pulse(locker);
    }
}
```

The current implementation uses the simplest approach, basically just quickly unlocking and locking again to give other threads an opportunity to jump in.

```
private void FastLoopCurrentImplementation()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (locker)
            DoWork();
    }
}
private void OtherThreadsCurrentImplementation()
{
    lock (locker)
        DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Something tells me this simplistic approach might have issues, though. If I'm not mistaken, the loop can just unlock and immediately lock again even though another thread is blocked. This would mean other methods may spend multiple main thread loop cycles blocked.

Am I right that this approach is not ideal? What would be the preferred method of locking/unlocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count blocked threads by you own:

```
private long blockedCount = 0;

private void FastLoop()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DoWork();

            while (Interlocked.Read(ref blockedCount) > 0)
                Monitor.Wait(locker);
        }
    }
}

private void OtherThreads()
{
    try
    {
        var wasBlocked = false;
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(locker))
        {
            wasBlocked = true;
            Interlocked.Increment(ref blockedCount);
            Monitor.Enter(locker);
        }

        DoSomethingElse();

        if (wasBlocked)
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref blockedCount);

        Monitor.Pulse(locker);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(locker);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should blockedCount be volatile? For the blockedCount > 0 check. It feels like it should be, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @relatively_random as far I know it's not a problem that `lock` acquired twice. And you are right about `Decrement` without  `Increment`. Let me update my answer

Comment: It is a problem if you don't *unlock* twice as well. Thanks for fixing!